# Problema com iteração em React

Tags: javascript, html5, react

Estou consumindo uma API, e colocando seus dados em uma 'li', só que está estourando a página pois mapeio todos os itens da api:

```
function showState(states){
    return states.map(state => <li key={state.nome}>{state.nome} - {state.sigla}</li>)
}
```

...

```
<div className="center">
            <ul>
                {response.data? showState(response.data): response.err}
            </ul>
 </div>
```

A ideia seria que o retorno da função showState gerasse algo do tipo, mas dinamicamente, limitando 9 'li' por 'ul':

```
<ul>
   <li>key={state[0].nome}>{state[0].nome} - {state[0].sigla}</li>
   <li>key={state[1].nome}>{state[1].nome} - {state[1].sigla}</li>
   <li>key={state[2].nome}>{state[2].nome} - {state[2].sigla}</li>
   ...
   <li key={state[8].nome}>{state[8].nome} - {state[8].sigla}</li>
</ul>
<ul>
   <li>key={state[9].nome}>{state[9].nome} - {state[9].sigla}</li>
   <li>key={state[10].nome}>{state[10].nome} - {state[10].sigla}</li>
   <li>key={state[11].nome}>{state[11].nome} - {state[11].sigla}</li>
   ...
   <li key={state[16].nome}>{state[16].nome} - {state[16].sigla}</li>
</ul>
<ul>
   <li>key={state[17].nome}>{state[17].nome} - {state[17].sigla}</li>
   <li>key={state[18].nome}>{state[18].nome} - {state[18].sigla}</li>
   <li>key={state[19].nome}>{state[19].nome} - {state[19].sigla}</li>
   ...
   <li key={state[26].nome}>{state[26].nome} - {state[26].sigla}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se entendi corretamente, **você precisa filtrar a quantidade de elementos para não renderizar tudo de uma vez**. A forma que acho mais fácil de fazer isso seria mantendo estado dos índices que deseja e usar a função [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) na sua lista `states`, algo como:

`const filteredStates = states.filter((state, index) => { if (index >= indexStart && index < indexLimit) return state; });`

E passar o `filteredStates` na chamada da sua função `showState`. Acontecendo algum evento disparado pelo usuário, por exemplo, você pode atualizar os valores das varíaveis `indexStart` e `indexLimit` chamando a função novamente. Isso faz com que apenas os itens com índice dentro do limite estabelecido retornem.

Espero ter ajudado de alguma forma.

Comment: Deu certo amigo, obrigado! A ideia era fazer algo mais dinâmico (sem precisar criar as <ul>) mas eu vou aprendendo com o tempo kkkk.

Uma dúvida, caso eu queira deixar a `const filteredStates` fora da função `showState ` eu teria q criar as variáveis indexStart e indexLimit e mudar elas pelo `useState()` certo?
E caso eu passasse a `const filteredStates` como um argumento pra função `showState()` e tambem os arguentos de  `indexStart` e `indexLimit`(dessa maneira `showState(filteredStates,0,9)`) aconteceria a comunicação entre a constante e os outros argumentos?? (nao sei se fui claro...)

Comment: Não precisa criar novamente a `ul`, você pode apenas renderizar a `ul` caso seu `indexStart` seja 0 ou já deixar a `ul` na página e retornar os `li` gradativamente. Sobre o `useState`, é isso mesmo. A ideia é controlar o estado delas no componente com `useState` e só passar o que deseja que retorne para a função.